# Is there a way to accept image as props in react component?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I am following react tutorial teaching by Bob Zirol in freecodecamp; in my App.js I have rendered a Card.js component which I passed an image as props; so how can I accept the image in my Card.js as props; because I did try several times without valid output; what I tried look like src={require('./images/$(props.img)')} but all didn't work. But the other text props I passed worked correctly

Comment: Can we see the value of the porps.img , a code of your problem would be better .

Comment: import React from "react";
import styles from "./styles.css";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import Hero from "./Hero";
import Card from "./Card";
import img from '/images/katie-zaferes.png';

export default function App(){
    return (
        
        <div>
           <Navbar />
           {/* <Hero /> */}
           <Card 
              img="katie-zaferes.png"
              rating="5.0"
              reviewCount={6}
              country="Nigeria"
              title="Life Lessons with Zaferes"
              price={135}
           />
        </div>
    )
}

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the image data as a prop the same way you would pass any other sort of data. From your comment below the question, it seems the image data you're trying to pass is `katie-zaferes.png`.

Pass the prop from the parent component to the child component:

```
import img from '/images/katie-zaferes.png'

const ParentComponent = () =>
{
    ...

    return <Card image = {img} />
}
```

Retrieve the prop in the child component:

```
const Card = (props) =>
{
    // /images/katie-zaferes.png
    const { image } = props

    ...
}
```

You can also just import the image directly into the child component, if that fits the structure of your project.